# IIS can't connect to SQL Server using SQL Server authentication

Tags: sql-server, iis

I have a very strange problem that I have tried to figure out for some time now but unsuccessfully. At work I am using a laptop for development. We have our application run locally on each developer's laptop, but we all use the same dev database. So when I take my work laptop home and connect it to our vpn, my laptop's IIS connects to SQL Server and everything works just fine.

The problem is when I try to use my personal desktop for work I connect it to the same vpn I connect my laptop to run the same code that is on the laptop with the same connection strings, but IIS can't connect to SQL Server and I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

On both computers I am able to connect to SQL Server using SSMS with no problem. On both computers I can run Integration Tests that hit the database just fine (integration tests use the exact same connection string that the application is using), but if I try to run the application it can't connect. I have tried changing all sorts of settings in IIS but to no avail.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can You post your application connection string. (not the identifying info of course just the structure)

Comment: Please telnet to the port sql serve is running.

Comment: It turned out that the problem was in the connection string for my IIS session state. It was pointing to a non existing server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure SQL Server Service is running
2. If a named instance, make sure SQL Server browser service is running
3. Make sure SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections
4. Examine the SQL Server error log for messages confirming that SQL is listening on the expected network interfaces and ports
5. Test server connectivity with PING from the client machine
6. Test port connectivity using TELNET or PowerShell to the server and port (from step 4) from the client machine.  For example
   a. TELNET  1433
   b. PowerShell: 1433 | % { echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("YourServerName",$*)) "server listening on TCP port $*" }
7. Check firewall settings if step 5 or 6 connectivity test fails